# While loop numerical patterns

Tags: java

1.)

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
```

2.)

```
999999999
88888888
7777777
666666
55555
4444
333
22
1
```

3.)

```
     5
    444
   33333
  2222222 
 111111111
```

These are the assignments I need to do.

I've only done this below:

```java
public static void main(String []args){
    int i, j;

    i = 1;
    while(i <= 10)
    {
        j = 1;
        while (j <= i) // limit the variable j by i 
        {
            System.out.print(j);
            j++;
        }

        System.out.println();
        i+;
    }
}
```

Which prints out:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
12345678910
```

I can't figure out how to do any of the 3 assignments above.
Any help?

Comment: One 1, two 2s, three 3s, then nine 9s, eight 8s, seven 7s - I'm seeing a pretty clear pattern there...

Comment: Maybe print `i` instead of `j` in the inner loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think the pattern is pretty obvious

1.)

```
String s;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    s = "";
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        s += i;
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

https://ideone.com/owLEG8

2.) You only have to reverse the 1st answer

3.)

```
String s;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    s = "";
    for(int j = 0; j < 5 - i; j++) {
        s += ' ';
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < 1 + i * 2; j++) {
        s += 5 - i;
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

https://ideone.com/prkNgs

Comment: I assumed the spacing is part of the `3)` pattern, so I formatted the question. @Andra: You might want to adjust the answer for that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, you can use `String.join()` and `Collections.nCopies()` to achieve this as follows:

1.)

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(i, String.valueOf(i))));
}
```

2.)

```
for (int i = 9; i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(i, String.valueOf(i))));
}
```

3.) Use `System.out.printf()` for formatting.

```
for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    String format = "%" + String.valueOf(10-i) + "s\n";
    System.out.printf(format, String.join("", Collections.nCopies((5-i)*2+1, String.valueOf(i))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 : Print i instead of j in 2nd while loop

Sample / Hint

```
while (j <= i) // limit the variable j by i 
        {
            System.out.print(i);
            j++;
        }
```

Case 2 : switch the positions of while loop, i.e., outer loop will decrease from max value to min value Or inner loop can finish decremental way

```
Not giving code so you can try and learn
```

Case 3 : Once you resolve 1 and 2, I am sure 3 will not be a big deal for you

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int i, space, rows=5, k=0;
        for(i=1; i<=rows; i++)
        {
            for(space=1; space<=(rows-i); space++)
            {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            while(k != (2*i-1))
            {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
                k++;
            }
            k = 0;
            System.out.println(); \\enter into new line
        }
    }
```

**ONLY WITH WHILE LOOPs (print reverse)**

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int i=1, space, rows=5, k=0;
        int j=rows;
        while(i<=5){

            space=rows;
            while(space>=i){

                System.out.print("  ");
                space--;
            }
            while(k != (2*i-1))
            {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
                k++;
            }
            k = 0;
            System.out.println(); //enter into new line
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
```

Happy to help you more but before that i wish you try your best.

Good luck

Comment: I did the first 2, but for the last one I wrote:                public static void main(String []args){
           int i, j;
 
       i = 5;
       while(i >= 1)
       {
           j = 5;
           while (j >= i) // limit the variable j by i
           {
 
               System.out.print(i);
               j--;
 
           }
 
           System.out.println();
           i--;
 
       }
   }                  and got 5 44 333 2222 11111

Comment: Glad you tried it. Updated my answer with old fashioned program

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I can only use while loops and no for loops.

Comment: Did you try to convert for loop into while?

Comment: I tried running it but it only printed the output from 1 - 5, and not 5 -1. I changed the i variable, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: I hope you tried your best. Sharing the code for your need. Check the last code block in above answer. Hope it helps.